# Flattening an nested object into a single row in NHidernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I've got one class nested in another:

```
public class InnerClass
{
    public string InnerProp1 { get; set; }
    public string InnerProp2 { get; set; }
}

public class OuterClass
{
    public string OuterProp1 { get; set; }
    public string OuterProp2 { get; set; }
    public InnerObject InnerClass { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to map it to this table:

```
CREATE TABLE FlatTable
(
    OuterProp1 VARCHAR(20),
    OuterProp2 VARCHAR(20),
    InnerProp1 VARCHAR(20),
    InnerProp2 VARCHAR(20),
)
```

I've tried a naive mapping

```
Property(x => x.OuterProp1);
Property(x => x.OuterProp2);
Property(x => x.InnerObject.InnerProp1);
Property(x => x.InnerObject.InnerProp2);
```

And this fails with a `ArgumentNullException` which I suspect is due to the `x.InnerObject` being null.

How can I create this mapping?

Comment: `public virutal string` all props HAVE to be virtual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using components

```
Property(x => x.OuterProp1);
Property(x => x.OuterProp2);
Component(
    x => x.InnerClass,
    comp =>
    {
        comp.Property(x => x.InnerProp1);
        comp.Property(x => x.InnerProp2);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, that's got me past most of the problem, but when I try and load it from the table the InnerClass is null.

Comment: OK, if I make the InerClass virtual then it gets created. @wudzik's comment helped with that.

Comment: Sorry, turns out I didn't need it to be virtual.